# Unsupported block type "bigquery_config" in Pubsub Subscription Push Bq

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, provider

Hello   I'm trying to create Pubsub Subscription Push Bq

this is my provider :

```
provider "google" {
  region  = "europe-west1"
  version = "~> 4.14.0"
  project = var.PROJECT_ID
}

provider "google-beta" {
  version = "~> 4.14.0"
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  backend "gcs" {}
}
```

This is my code snippet :

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "standarized_vehicles_subscription" {
  name  = var.bq_sub_name 
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.topic_standarized_vehicles.name
  
  bigquery_config {
    table = "${var.project}:${var.dataset_id}.${var.bq_table_id}"
    use_topic_schema = true
    drop_unknown_fields = true
  }
  
  depends_on = [google_project_iam_member.bq_viewer, google_project_iam_member.bq_editor]

}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "bq_viewer" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role   = "roles/bigquery.metadataViewer"
  member = "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "bq_editor" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role   = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
  member = "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

But when i try to plan -> apply my code i get this error

```
Error: Unsupported block type
  on blueprint/pubsub.tf line 181, in resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "standarized_vehicles_subscription":
 181:   bigquery_config {
Blocks of type "bigquery_config" are not expected here.
```

My version support all  4.x.x range, as long as it is greater than or equal to version 4.14.0 and less than version 5.0.0.
`bigquery_config block` should be supported in this version so what can cause this error?
Thanks for your help

Comment: You probably want a newer version of the GCP provider. The way you have it set up currently will allow only minor version upgrades, i.e., `4.14.x`.

Comment: As Marko said, provider version is the most likely issue. Suggest upgrading to latest, and then update required providers accordingly. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/requirements